# How to prove that trigonometric functions form a Chebyshev system?

Tags: functional-analysis, numerical-methods

How can be proven that $$\{ \operatorname{cos}(kx)\}_{k = 0}^n \text{ and } \{ \operatorname{sin}(kx)\}_{k = 1}^n$$
are [Chebyshev systems](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Chebyshev_system) in the interval $(0, \pi)$? Any ideas will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I added a reference to Chebyshev systems. Generally, it's a good idea to do this in order to avoid misunderstanding of the terminology. Also, you should have shared any progress you've made on the problem thus far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A really simple proof:
  Let $T_n(x) \in \pi_n$ denotes the $n$-th Chebyshev polinomyal of 1-st kind. We have that $T_k(\cos(x))=\cos(kx)$.
  Therafore any non-trivial polynomial from $\{\cos(kx)\}_{k=0}^n=\{T_k(\cos(x))\}_{k=0}^n$ is actually a polinomyal of degree at most $n$ for $\cos(x)$ and it has at most $n$ zeroes ($\xi_1, \xi_2, ..., \xi_m$) where $m \leq n$. Since $cos(x)$ is injective in $(0,\pi)$ we have that $ \forall i=1,2,...,m$ $\exists!x_i:  \cos(x_i)=\xi_i$
  So now we have that any non-trivial polynomial from $\{\cos(kx)\}_{k=0}^n$ has at most $n$ (particularly distinct) zeroes in $(0,\pi)$.
  About $\{\sin(kx)\}_{k=1}^n$ check this out...
  Let $\varphi(x)=\lambda_0+\lambda_1\cos(x)+...+\lambda_n\cos(nx)$ is a non-trivial polynomial for $\{\cos(kx)\}_{k=0}^n$ and at least one of $\lambda_1,...,\lambda_n \neq 0$.
  It has at most $n$ zeroes in $(0,\pi)$. Now, we have that $\varphi'(x)=g(\cos(x))(-\sin(x))$ where $g(\cos(x))$ is a polynomial from degree $n-1$. Since $\sin(x) \neq 0$ and $\cos(x)$ is injective for $x \in (0,\pi)$ we conclude that $\varphi'(x)=g(\cos(x))(-\sin(x))$ has at most $n-1$ zeroes in $(0,\pi)$.
  On the other hand $\varphi '(x)=-\lambda_1 \sin(x)-...-n\lambda_n \sin (nx)$ which is a non-trivial polynomial for $\{\sin(kx)\}_{k=1}^n$. Therefore every non-trivial polynomial over $\{\sin(kx)\}_{k=1}^n$ has at most $n-1$ distinct zeroes...

Comment: Wow brilliant! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hey, doesn't Rolle's theorem give us a lower bound for the zeroes? I mean if $\phi(x)$ has $k$ distinct zeroes, then $\phi'(x)$ has at least $k-1$ distinct zeroes? How can you bound them from above?

Comment: Oh, I got it! $\sum_{k = 0}^{n} \lambda_i \cos kx = f(\cos x)$, where $f$ is polynomial of degree at most $n$. Then $(f(\cos x))' = g(\cos x) (-\sin x)$, where $g$ is of degree at most $n-1$. $\sin x$ can't be zero for $x \in (0, \pi)$, so the zeroes of $(f(\cos x))'$ are the zeroes of $g(\cos x)$ and therefore at most $n-1$! Edit the wrong part of your answer!

Comment: Yes, you are right... I don't know why I even mentioned Rolle's theorem

Answer (score 0):

Linear independence follows from $L^2$ orthogonality. That is, the functions are $L^2$-orthogonal (this is a calculus exercise) and orthogonality implies linear independence regardless of the inner product in question. I'll leave that to you; ask in the comments if you need help with it.

Revised:

For zero counting, you can write any linear combination of cosines of angular frequencies $1,2,\dots,n$ as a polynomial of degree at most $n$ in the variable $\cos(x)$ by using the sum-to-product and product-to-sum formulas repeatedly. The actual formula doesn't matter at all, so I don't suggest writing it down; all that matters is that such a polynomial exists.

Having done this transformation, you can now use the fundamental theorem of algebra to get that $\cos(x)$ must be one of at most $n$ values. Then $\cos$ is injective on $(0,\pi)$, so $x$ must be one of at most $n$ values as well. A formal proof would use induction and this general idea.

The case with $\sin$ is slightly more complicated because $\sin$ is *not* injective on $(0,\pi)$; here I think you need to exploit the odd symmetry in order to get the result.

Comment: Thanks! But can you explain what is $L^2$ orthogonality. Also if I'm not missing something you are dealing only with the cases when just one of the coefficients of the cos$(kx)$ is not zero. What happens if we have linear combination of two or more cosines (or this follows from the linear independence of the functions)?

Comment: These functions are orthogonal in the sense of the inner product $\langle f,g \rangle = \int_0^\pi f(x) g(x) dx$, which is called the $L^2$ inner product. The zero-counting property is not intended to apply to linear combinations if I understand correctly.

Comment: OK I got that $cos(kx)$ has $k$ zeroes. What I'm asking for is if we have such function : $\sum_{k = 0}^{n} a_k cos(kx)$ where two or more of the $a_i$ are not zero. How can we be sure that it wouldn't have more than $n$ zeroes?

Comment: @brick Never mind, I see now. Let me think about it.

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Comment: @brick A sketch: any such linear combination is a polynomial of degree at most $n$ in the variable $\cos(x)$, using the sum-to-product formulas repeatedly. Now use the fundamental theorem of algebra and note that $\cos(x)$ is injective on $(0,\pi)$.

Comment: Ah, OK. Thanks!

Comment: Would the downvoters care to comment? john's answer is essentially the same as mine for the cosine case, and he doesn't elaborate on the issue of linear independence. So I don't see why I should be downvoted over not elaborating about the sine case.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the map $\cos x=\frac{1}{2}(e^{ix}+e^{-ix})$ and $\sin x=\frac{1}{2i}(e^{ix}-e^{-ix})$ in $T(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{n}\cos (ix)$ we get a  polynomial $P(z)=T(x)e^{inx}$ Here $z=e^{ix}$ maps $[a,a+2\pi]$ to unit circle $|z|=1.$ Clearly, if $T$ has more than $2n$ zeros, then $P$ has so. So $P$ must be identically zero. This means $T$ is also identically zero.(G. G. Lorentz PP. 24)