# Chebyshev System and Trigonometric polynomials

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-optimization, numerical-calculus

For $j\in\mathbb{N}_0$ let $\sin_j(x)=\sin(jx)$ and $\cos_j(x)=\cos(jx)$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. How do I prove that the finite series of functions
$$
(1,\cos_1,\sin_1, \cos_2, \sin_2,...,\cos_m,\sin_n)
$$
is a $\mathbb{R}$-Chebyshev-system for $n\in\mathbb{N}_0$ on $\mathbb{R}/2\pi \cong (-\pi,\pi]$?

Thankfull for every answer and your help!

EDIT: Definition of a Chebyshev-System

"A system of linearly independent functions $S=(ϕ_i)_{i=0}^n$ in a space $C(Q)$ with the property that no non-trivial polynomial in this system has more than n−1 distinct zeros."$

Comment: What is a Chebyshev system?

Comment: I edited it, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}_{\geq 1}$ be a fixed order. Based, for example, on the books

- Dunham Jackson, 1930. The Theory of Approximation, American Mathematical Society, Colloquium Publications, Vol. XI,
- Samuel Karlin, 1968. Total Positivity, Vol. I, Stanford University Press, Stanford, California, p. 266, equation (7.19),

we know that
\begin{align}
&~\det
\left(
\begin{array}{cccccccc}
1 & \cos\left(x_0\right) & \sin\left(x_0\right) & \cdots & \cos\left(nx_0\right) & \sin\left(nx_0\right)\\
1 & \cos\left(x_1\right) & \sin\left(x_1\right) & \cdots & \cos\left(nx_1\right) & \sin\left(nx_1\right)\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & & \vdots & \vdots\\
1 & \cos\left(x_{2n}\right) & \sin\left(x_{2n}\right) & \cdots & \cos\left(nx_{2n}\right) & \sin\left(nx_{2n}\right)\\
\end{array}
\right)
\\
\\~
=&
~2^{2n^2} \prod_{0\leq j < i \leq 2n} \sin\left(\frac{x_i - x_j}{2}\right) > 0\end{align}
whenever
$$
x_0 < x_1 < \ldots < x_{2n} < x_0 + 2\pi.
$$

If I am not mistaken, your question is equivalent to the inequality cited above. (Considering the exponent of the factor $2^{2n^2}$ (appearing before the product operator), it seems, that equation (7.19) of [Karlin, 1968] contains a typo.)

You may also check the [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1065537/how-to-prove-that-trigonometric-functions-form-a-chebyshev-system) given to a very similar question.